# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when /tmp mounted as noexec while using Mongo CSFLE (mongodb-crypt)

Tags: java, linux, mongodb, jna, mongodb-java

I have been working on MongoDB CSFLE (Client-Side Field-Level Encryption) for which there is a dependency in my spring boot project `mongodb-crypt-1.0.1`. For security reasons, the `/tmp` partition is mounted as `noexec` on Ubuntu 16.04 OS running on an EC2. The application startup fails with the following stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/jna--851256601/jna10844749069600633969.tmp: /tmp/jna--851256601/jna10844749069600633969.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2430) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2487) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2684) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2617) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:767) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1834) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:947) ~[jna-4.5.2.jar!/:4.5.2 (b0)]
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:922) ~[jna-4.5.2.jar!/:4.5.2 (b0)]
    at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:190) ~[jna-4.5.2.jar!/:4.5.2 (b0)]
    at com.mongodb.crypt.capi.CAPI.<clinit>(CAPI.java:778) ~[mongodb-crypt-1.0.1.jar!/:?]
    at com.mongodb.crypt.capi.MongoCryptImpl.<init>(MongoCryptImpl.java:92) ~[mongodb-crypt-1.0.1.jar!/:?]
    at com.mongodb.crypt.capi.MongoCrypts.create(MongoCrypts.java:36) ~[mongodb-crypt-1.0.1.jar!/:?]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.Crypts.createCrypt(Crypts.java:35) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.3.jar!/:?]
...
```

The application starts up just fine when the `/tmp` is mounted as `exec` instead.

Is there any way to solve this without making `/tmp` executable?

Comment: JNA needs a temp dir to write its native stub to, but you can specify a different directory by changing the `jna.tmpdir` property to one that's not `noexec`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! This solves the problem!

Comment: Heh, guess I should have made it an answer, although it was an educated guess!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell the crypto parts use JNA and in particular use it to extract libmongocrypt.so into a temporary directory by default. The relevant documentation I believe is https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/GettingStarted.md.

I suggest trying:

1. Setting `jna.library.path` to a path that is on a filesystem with execution allowed (and copying libmongocrypt.so manually there?).
2. If this doesn't work, try downloading libmongocrypt.so manually and placing it into a path that your OS can load libraries from without configuration. The download instructions should be the same as for Ruby driver which are [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/client-side-encryption/#installation), use the `nocrypto` version of libmongocrypt.

Edit: `jna.tmpdir` seems more appropriate per the comment.

Comment: Thanks Oleg! Supplying `-Djna.tmpdir` to java solves the problem. Thankfully, no manual work needed :). Your answer clarifies why exactly this is needed though.